# My mesh looks awry

Tags: mesh, topology

It can be a basic question.

I made random shape to explain my situation.
This object is basically box shaped and a round shaped hole is connected.
[image]
And these kind of shadows in both sides makes me frustrated sometimes...
Weird shadow and gloss are on same simple surface without any doubles.

The mesh is just as itself, welded as one.
Please [take a look](https://gofile.io/d/FDZGyx) and tell me what's the problem.

And I'm new to topologies too, so I welcome advices for making good flows on mesh.

Comment: please attach your blend file.  You might have bad geometry, such as extra faces or doubled vertices, or you may just need to enable auto-smooth in object data properties. But it's hard to tell without looking at the actual blend file.

Comment: There is a blend file attached, that's how I made my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this is that your object is shaded smooth, and it's smoothed around the sharp edges. Usually *Autosmooth* avoids this, but in your case it's not working because under *Object Data Properties* > *Geometry Data* you have stored custom data. To make *Autosmooth* work again, click on the button *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*.

[image: clear custom split normals data]

Comment: Thank you! It totally fixed my mesh.

Comment: @user123730 Maybe you would consider to mark this answer as accepted so that other users can see there is a solution to this question. Read here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I just voted up but my reputation is only 11 because I just signed up. However they said my feedback is recorded.

Comment: You don't need more reputation to accept an answer. Just click on the grey tickmark under the vote number.

Comment: Oh, I found the tick mark! Thanks again.